Integration in the complex plane
I want to compute the definite integral of the following function between $-\infty$ and $+\infty$:
\begin{equation}
f(\omega)= \frac{R (\tau \omega-i b) e^{i \omega t}}{(\omega+i) (b+i \tau \omega)-i} 
\end{equation}
assuming that $\tau >0, R>0$ and $b>0$. I'm a little rusty with residue calculus, but barring a mistake on my part, I think that's the shortest way to the solution.
The function above has two poles and more exactly:
\begin{equation}
\omega_1 = \frac{i \left(\sqrt{b^2+2 b \tau +\tau ^2-4 \tau }+b-\tau \right)}{2 \tau }
\end{equation}
And
\begin{equation}
\omega_2= -\frac{i \left(\sqrt{b^2+2 b \tau +\tau ^2-4 \tau }-b+\tau \right)}{2 \tau }
\end{equation}
As expected the poles come in complex conjugate pairs.
Using the Cauchy residue theorem we have:
\begin{equation}
\int_{\infty}^{+\infty} f(\omega) d\omega=2 \pi i \sum_{j=1}^N Res(f(z),z_j)
\end{equation}
Because the denominator of the $f(\omega)$ is not 2 degrees greater than the degree of numerator, I am not sure the integral converge.
Now I have to choose the integration contour in the complex plane. This contour, enclosing the singularities of $f(z)$, can be defined using a semicircle in the upper or lower complex half-plane.
In other words, the integral will have to be calculated by choosing either the pole with positive imaginary part, if the semicircle in the upper complex half plane is considered
or the pole with negative imaginary part otherwise.
When I consider the pole $\omega_1$ the integral results:
\begin{equation}
\int_{\infty}^{+\infty} f(\omega) d \omega=\frac{\pi  R \left(\sqrt{(b+\tau )^2-4 \tau }-b-\tau \right) e^{-\frac{t \left(\sqrt{(b+\tau )^2-4 \tau }+b-\tau \right)}{2 \tau
   }}}{\sqrt{(b+\tau )^2-4 \tau }}
\end{equation}
I implicitly made the assumption that $(b+\tau)^{2}-4 \tau>0$ and that therefore $\omega_1$ is the pole with positive imaginary part and $\omega_2$ is the one with negative imaginary part.
Instead, when I consider the lower complex half-plane I have:
\begin{equation}
\int_{\infty}^{+\infty} f(\omega) d \omega=\frac{\pi  R \left(\sqrt{(b+\tau )^2-4 \tau }+b+\tau \right) e^{\frac{t \left(\sqrt{(b+\tau )^2-4 \tau }-b+\tau \right)}{2 \tau
}}}{\sqrt{(b+\tau )^2-4 \tau }}
\end{equation}
This two way of computing the integral should provide the same results, but this is not the case. My conclusion is that because the denominator degree is not 2 degrees greater than the degree of numerator, the integral along the complex half-plane circle is not necessarily equal to zero. Am I correct? In this case how is it possible to compute the integral using the residues?
My final question is what if the hypothesis $(b+\tau)^{2}-4 \tau>0$ cannot be verified, e.g., because both $b$ and $\tau$ can take values such that $\sqrt{(b+\tau )^2-4 \tau }<0$?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Hi, $\tau$ is not $t$, and the exponential $e^{i \omega t}$ is correct. The integral I want to compute is proportional to the inverse Fourier transform of $f(\omega) e^{-i \omega t}$.
